# Redeem / Activate Explorer's pack Elder scrolls online

Tags: xbox-one, the-elder-scrolls-online

Does anyone know how to activate the Explorer's pack (for the vanity pet mainly) on Xbox one? I've redeemed the code and store says that I've purchased it, but can't, for the life of me manage to activate the content :(

**update** Read at online community site that items such as this are sent via in-game mail, yet going through to social->mail shows "no mail".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pets are no longer sent. You should receive your treasure maps later today or tomorrow by the mail system (might take a bit due to heavy load right after launch).

As for your vanity pet, open the game's main menu using the menu button, then look under "Collections". There's a sub menu for pets, which should include the preorder bonus.

Activate or deactivate it at any time.

Comment: Okay thanks. As for the pets, I've checked that menu and I've only got some spider which is unlocked after XYZ.

Comment: Might just take some time to apply then. You can also check character creation. If the Explorer Pack has been redeemed, you should be able to create any race/alliance combination (like Daggerfall Covenant Argonian).

Comment: Yes, you can test it by trying to create a Khajiit in the Ebonheart Pact, for example. In addition to that, ZeniMax is having some issues because of the launch - so if you haven't got anything from within 3 days, you may start a support ticket. :)